# Create Collection with Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm sure this is possible with a custom script node but is there any out of the box way to create a collection with animation nodes? Currently I'm creating a bunch of objects in my node graph and would like to group them into a collection. I.e every 3 objects gets put into a new collection.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create collections with Animation Nodes. If you need to group objects then you can create a list of objects then iterate in them with loops or use vectorized nodes. Or you can just create collections manually.